# Changing LinkedIn Developer App Name Dynamically

Tags: linkedin-api

My iOS app allows LinkedIn users to login using the LinkedIn OAuth.  The app is branded for different clients, so I would like to change my LinkedIn Developer Application name to match the clients name, so that the LinkedIn web signin page text reads " would like to access some of your LinkedIn info:"

Is this possible? Creating a LinkedIn application for each client is not practical.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change your application name dynamically.

Comment: Ok, thx.  I have a reasonable work-around.  I'm setting the app name at LinkedIn to "This app".  That way the message displayed to the user is something like "This app would like to access..."